# Is this a real Kinetic?

Tags: trainer

Someone on Craigslist is selling this Kinetic bike trainer for $100. I was interested when I saw the title, but I thought Kurt Kinetic trainers were green and this looks wrong. Is this a knockoff?
[image: maybe kinetic]

Comment: Could be the lighting and the photo - the right side certainly looks Dark Green to me.

Comment: Insert <Famous blue/black/gold dress comment> here.

Comment: There are several black examples in the results of an google image search for "Kurt kinetic original" so I'd guess it's real.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @SLR.

Comment: Observation - the leg on the right of the photo seems to be off the ground.  Could it be bent?  Or just not fully adjusted .

Comment: These are all good observations! It might be bent or it might be on an uneven surface. Either way, I decided not to buy it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a real Kinetic. The older Kinetics used to be black and had a much different logo. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5X2Y.jpg]

"But for some time now, I’ve been wondering how much different the Kurt Kinetic Road Machine is from my ‘old’ trainer. Well, it turns out that Kurt Kinetic hit on a winner with the original design… and except for a new ‘hair color’, the two units are nearly identical. Wisely, Kurt Kinetic decided to not fix something that isn’t broken." http://cycling-review.com/accessories/bicycle-trainer/kurt-kinetic-road-trainer/

Comment: Excellent finding the answer and a good photo, and also for coming back and sharing it.  +1